# What words that have vowel + s + vowel are pronunced /s/ instead of /z/?

Tags: pronunciation

Italian words with the format vowel + s + vowel are typically pronounced /z/, like:

- me**s**e
- co**s**a
- e**s**ercizio

But some words break this rule, and are pronounced /s/, like:

- sta**s**era (because it comes from "sera", which has an initial s and is always pronounced /s/)
- pre**s**idente (I don't know if there's a reason for this one)

Are there any other words that follow the pattern of "stasera" and "presidente"?

Comment: What is "mesa"? However I've got the feeling that this would be too broad to be answered here.

Comment: You're right, I meant mese, I'll change it. I don't know about broad, I'd just like to know if there are any other words. Those are the only two I could find

Comment: Right, but "prestare" isn't vowel + s + vowel. All words that have an "s" followed by a consonant like "t" are pronounced /s/

Comment: Ah you're right! Then I'll go for "presidiare" ("presidio", "presidi", "presidia", [...], "presidiante", "presidiato", [...])

Comment: Who told you that [*mese*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mese/) or [*cosa*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cosa/) are pronounced with /z/? Treccani and many Italians (especially in Tuscany) disagree.

Comment: That's a good one, although I think that presidente, presidiare and presiedere share the same etymological root.

Comment: @DaG this dictionary http://www.dipionline.it/dizionario/ricerca?lemma=cosa is there any other you'd recommend using?

Comment: The one you mention, edited by Canepari, is very interesting but possibly misleading when learning Italian, because it registers all actual uses in different regional Italians (you may see several variants already in the page you link). The “official” pronunciation of *cosa* is undoubtedly with /s/ (while a typical example of /z/ is *rosa*, the flower). A standard reference is [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/), which doesn't use IPA, but a simple but adequate system: in particular, /z/ is an “s” with a dot on it, while /s/ is just “s”.

Comment: For one more example, try telling /piza/ (as some Italians do) to someone from Pisa (/pisa/).

Comment: @DaG, you make a good point. The [forvo page](http://forvo.com/word/casa/#it) for "casa" lists both /casa/ and /caza/. You recommend I go by Treccani and pronounce it /casa/?

Comment: Yes, personally I'd suggest to begin by following “standard Italian” pronunciation, and at the same time – if so inclined – paying attention to the different regional variants. For instance, you'll notice that *zio* (“uncle”) is often pronounced /dzio/ rather than the “standard” /tsio/; and some people, especially in the North, open their closed vowels, so that /per'ke/ (*perché*, “why/because”) becomes /per'kɛ/, orthographical cue notwithstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a fixed rule for which words in which an intervocalic “s” occurs are to be pronounced with a /s/ and which ones with a /z/. Short of having well clear the origin and evolution of each word, one has to check each on a dictionary.

Of the examples in the question, the tradizional, standard Italian pronunciation for *mese* is /'mese/ (see [Dizionario di ortografia e pronunzia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=39794&r=7197) by Migliorini et al., [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mese/), [De Mauro dictionary](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mese), the paper ones I have checked – Devoto-Oli, Zingarelli – etc.), for *cosa* is /'kɔsa/ ([DOP](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=75177&r=888), [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cosa/), [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cosa)), while for *esercizio* is /ezer'tʃitsjo/ ([DOP](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=60600&r=11167), [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esercizio/), [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/esercizio)). So two out of three have /s/ rather than /z/.

Other works, like the already mentioned one by Canepari, take into account regional variants which can differ from these.

Especially for a foreigner studying Italian, personally I'd suggest to begin by following “standard Italian” pronunciation, while at the same time – if so inclined – paying attention to the different regional variants. For instance, one will notice that *zio* (“uncle”) is often pronounced /dzio/ rather than the “standard” /tsio/; and some people, especially in the North, open their closed vowels, so that /per'ke/ (*perché*, “why/because”) becomes /per'kɛ/, orthographical cue notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1):

According to the "Dizionario di Pronuncia Italiana" of L. Canepari, the modern and neutral pronunciation tends to use /*s*/ (unvoiced) between vowels only in the case of composite words, in which the second element starts with -*sV*- (V is any vowel) and maintains an independent semantic value. This is the case of "*stasera*" and "*presidente*" (comes from the Latin present participle *praesidēre* formed by "*siedere*" with "*pre*" as a prefix). Other examples are: "*controsenso*", "*caposala*", "*presalario*", "*risalire*", "*risaltare*", "*girasole*", etc. Despite this general rule you can hear /-*VzV*-/ in the South.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am Italian native speaker but not a linguist nor an expert of any sort.

In my experience this is highly regional and maybe even simply north / south.
F.ex. I cannot imagine anyone from Napoli (south Italy) pronouncing "mese" or "cosa" with the /z/ (it's always /s/) and I cannot imagine anyone from Bologna (north Italy) pronouncing them with /s/ (it's always /z/).

Actually - as I lived many years in the north - I'm trying to think of any "vowel + s + vowel" non-composite word that a northerner would pronounce with /s/ and none is coming to my mind. I will update this post if some does come to my mind.

Comment: I remember a priest in Catania who always said /spiritozanto/, pronouncing “Spirito Santo” as a single word.

Answer (score 0):

You claim your first examples to be an "S sonora". I couldn't understand the difference, because in my Italian pronunciation (I am a native Italian speaker) all your examples sound the same.
So I did some research and it turns out that, as a general rule, vowel + s + vowel should be a "S sorda" (your second list of examples), but exceptions might arise depending of the region in Italy, making your question very interesting to me.
I hope this wikipedia page helps you: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_sorda

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: *Esercizio* con la “s sorda” mi farebbe rizzare i capelli, esattamente come *Brasile* con lo stesso suono.

Comment: Ok, apprezzo la tua opinione, per me sono entrambi accettabili.